# Finding a recurrence for number of sequences

Tags: combinatorics

We have first $N$ natural numbers.
Let $f(n,k)$ denote number of sequences using $n$ distinct natural numbers such that there are $\le k$ terms in the sequence such they are smaller than their next term i.e $a_x < a_{x+1}$.
Eg: $1,3,2,4$ has $2$ terms where $a_x<a_{x+1}$ and those are $1$ and $2$.
My approach:
We can fill the first two positions in $^nC_2$ ways, then we can use recurrence at length $n-2$. We can either make $a_1<a_2$ and add $f(n-2,k-1)$ to our answer or do the reverse and add $f(n-2,k)$.
$$\therefore f(n,k)=\left(^nC_2\right)f(n-2,k) + \left(^nC_2\right)f(n-2,k-1)$$
But it can also happen that $a_2<a_3$ and that can affect the recurrence relation of $f(n,k)$ How can I adapt this thing to my recurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the jargon of combinatorics of permutations, you are looking for
permutations of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ which have at most $k$ *ascents*.
The number of permutations of $[n]$ with exactly $k$ ascents is
called an Eulerian number $A(n,k)$. So $f(n,k)=A(n,0)+A(n,1)+\cdots+A(n,k)$.
The Eulerian numbers satisfy the recurrence
$$A(n,k)=(n-k)A(n-1,k-1)+(k+1)A(n-1,k).$$
You may be able to get a recurrence for $f(n,k)$ from this. I'd try putting
$A(n,k)=f(n,k)-f(n,k-1)$.

Comment: Thanks.  
What if we have to count sequences of n terms with $\le k$ terms that either have greater element in front of them or behind them.

Comment: @maverick that's a good question: you want to avoid "troughs" with $a_{j-1}>a_j<a_{j+1}$. I don't know the answer to this, but I would start off investigating it by considering the number of permutations with exactly $k$ troughs.